# How to use set path correctly in this?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to setup the batch file is fit for different user. So I try to make the batch file a bit easier, then I use "set path" in the batch file, after I run, nothing is copy. Please instruct

- The source: C:\Users\basex\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes
- The destination: C:\Users\basex\Desktop\BACKUP\backup testing

And the Code that I'm using is:

```
@echo off
Set path=%source%;"C:\Users\basex\"
echo f | xcopy /s /h /y "%source%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt" "%source%\Desktop\BACKUP\backup testing"

pause
```

Comment: `%path%` is already a system variable. Do **NOT** overwrite its value.

Comment: In fact, it's exactly _because_ you're overwriting `%path%` that xcopy (which is a program, not a command) isn't working.

Comment: thanks for responding, even though i changed the "path" to "source" still not working properly. please instruct more

Comment: You misunderstood me. Do not set path at all. Delete the entire line from your script.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt window and execute in this window `set` to get listed all predefined environment variables. You see in the list

- `PATH` ... semicolon separated list of folders to search for executables and scripts.
- `PATHEXT` ... semicolon separated list of file extensions for executables and scripts.

Those two environment variables are used to find `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe` on having entered in console or in a batch file just `xcopy` without file extension and without path. `SystemRoot` is another predefined environment variable.

By overwriting predefined `PATH` with the two folder paths, Windows command processor can't find anymore `xcopy.exe` in system folder of Windows.

The list contains also other useful environment variables like

- `USERNAME` ... name of the current user account.
- `USERPROFILE` ... path to the profile directory of the current user account.
- `APPDATA` ... path to the application data directory of the current user account.

Run in command prompt window also `xcopy /?` to get displayed the help for this standard Windows console application which is not an internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe`.

Your task can be done with a single command line:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\" /H /I /Q /R /Y >nul
```

This command line copies the file `StickyNotes.snt` from `Sticky Notes` application data directory of current user to a backup directory in desktop directory of the current user with creating automatically the entire directory structure to the backup directory if that would be necessary.

By the way: The desktop directory of a user should contain only shortcuts in my point of view, i.e. *.lnk files and not files and folders. I suggest to have the backup directory in user profile directory and have on desktop a shortcut to this backup directory for easy accessing it from Windows desktop.

The internal command `copy` is usually used to copy a single file and not `xcopy`, but there might be reasons for using `xcopy` which I don't know.